# SAP Web IDE: Better multiple Cursors

Tags: sap-web-ide

In SAP Web IDE it offers a manual way of using multiple cursors. I'm used to using this via `Ctrl+D` and I find this manual way of doing it frustrating.

Is there any way to add the `Ctrl+D` way via a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to have the `Ctrl + D` functionality in the SAP Web IDE (Full-Stack). Now we discovered that there is a **similar** functionality implemented where you can have a cursor at each occurrence of the searched term.

[image: cursor at each occurrence]

- select the string you want to search for
- press `Ctrl + F`
- press `Alt + Enter` to get a cursor at each occurrence of the searched string

Of course it´s a bit more complicated than just pressing `Ctrl + D` in other editors like Atom, VS Code, ...

I would also appreciate a way to only get one more cursor per shortcut-press and not a cursor for each occurrence in the whole file.

Another thing which helped me was the `Shift + Alt` shortcut to get a cursor in each line underneath each other:

[image: cursor in each line]

- place the cursor in the line where you want to have the first cursor
- press `Shift + Alt` and keep it pressed
- click at the line where you want to have your last cursor and release `Shift + Alt`

I hope this helps.